# SQL: Multiple select that differ by only one condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a beginner question. My SQL table looks like:

```
|   Date   | Type | Manufacturer |
2016/04/01    A         X
2016/04/01    B         Y
2016/04/02    B         X
2016/05/07    A         Z
  ...        ...       ...
```

My aim is to count the quantity of "Types" by manufacturers between two dates. I would like to get a result like following:

```
| Manufacturer | Quantity_TypeA | Quantity_TypeB |
   X               1                 1
   Y               0                 1
   Z               1                 0
```

My query looks like:

```
 select Manufacturer as Manufacturer, 
 COUNT(*) as Quantity_TypeA
 From MyTable
 Where [Type] = 'A' and 
 Date between '20150101' and '20160930',
 COUNT(*) as Quantity_TypeB
 From MyTable 
 Where [Type] = 'B' and 
 Date between '20150101' and '20160930'    
 group by Manufacturer Order by Quantity_TypeA DESC
```

I have also tried to use functions like CASE on the Type and it didn't work. I am missing something but what?

Comment: Seems like you have some kind of date format inconsistency. Column Date's data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select Manufacturer as Manufacturer, 
 SUM(case when [Type] = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Quantity_TypeA,
 SUM(case when [Type] = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as Quantity_TypeB
 From MyTable
 Where 
 Date between '20150101' and '20160930'
group by Manufacturer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select Manufacturer as Manufacturer, 
       COUNT(case when [Type] = 'A' then 1 end) as Quantity_TypeA,
       COUNT(case when [Type] = 'B' then 1 end) as Quantity_TypeB
from MyTable
where Date between '20150101' and '20160930',
group by Manufacturer
order by Quantity_TypeA DESC
```

`count()` does only count non-null values. The `case` expressions either return 1 or null, i.e. only A's or B's are counted.